# Unable to provision Migrate for compute engine (Velostrata) from GCP marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration

I'm trying to provision a Velostrata from the Marketplace, but there's an error:

```
{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"412","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":412,"message":"Precondition check failed.","status":"FAILED_PRECONDITION","statusMessage":"Precondition failed"
```

*Note*: I've already created the service account by using the python script from cloud shell, even when I've tried to create the service account manually I've got the same issue.

I have Organization Admin, Project Owner and all the required access for my IAM account.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Configuring Google Cloud
](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/configuring-gcp/configuring-gcp) and update your question with your steps and commands: **1**. [Setting up a Google Cloud account, organization, and infrastructure project](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/configuring-gcp/configuring-gcp#setting_up_a_account_organization_and_infrastructure_project) **2**. [Setting up network](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/configuring-gcp/configuring-gcp#setting_up_network)

Comment: **3**. [Creating roles and service accounts via Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/configuring-gcp/configuring-gcp#creating_roles_and_service_accounts_via_cloud_shell). The more details you provide the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this, The reason for the error was external IP restriction on the project level. Once after i disabled it everything is working fine now.